# insertion time of this record to your new data when altering table(inserting new data) in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Example Hive table:

```
id|year
1|1990
```

Added new data for the same table :

```
id|year
2|2010
```

but i need insertion time with new column like:

```
id|year|updateddate
1|1990|olddatatimestamp
2|2010|updateddatatimestamp
```

is this possible with hive ? and even interested to know how this will do in spark-scala as well(specially with DF/RDD).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no auto-calculated columns in Hive, insert the timestamp explicitly using `current_timestamp`. And of course you need to add `updateddate` column:

```
insert into table tablename
select 2 as ID, 2010 as year, current_timestamp as updateddate;
```